# vk.api не работает проверка на репост

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

В разделе `<head>` своего сайта я подключаю vk api.

```
<script src='//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

Далее я создал функцию vk_share для обработки проверки на репост.

```
function vk_share()
{
    VK.init({
        apiId: my_id
    });
    console.log(VK.Api);
    VK.Observer.subscribe("widgets.like.shared", function f(){
        alert("Thank you for your shared.");
    });
}
```

И по клику я вызываю функцию:

```
<a onclick="vk_share()" target="_blank" href="http://vk.com/share.php?image=http://mysite.ru/pic4vk.jpg&description=Описание &url=http://mysite.ru&title=Заголовок"><img src="img/socials/vk.jpg" alt=""/></a>
```

Репост генерируется нормально, но алерт после совершения пользователем репоста не происходит. 
Подскажите как правильно проверять на репост вк.
 **UPD1** по совету Александра попытался добавить виджет

```
VK.Widgets.Like("vk_like", {type: "button"});
```

Получаю следующую ошибку:

```
VK.Widgets: object #vk_like not found.
```

Также добавил onlyWidget true.
Код функции проверки репоста сейчас вот такой

```
    function vk_share()
    {
        VK.init({
            apiId: 5216642,
            onlyWidgets: true
        });
        VK.Widgets.Like("vk_like", {type: "button"});
        console.log(VK.Api);
        VK.Observer.subscribe("widgets.like.shared", function f(){
            alert("Thank you for your shared.");
        });
    }
```

Comment: Данный обсервер относится к виджету «Мне нравится»
http://vk.com/dev/Like

Comment: Гугл ничего дельного по этой ошибке мне не выдал. @Alexander

Comment: проблема в том, что вы не используете виджет, к которому относится данное событие. Вы вообще виджет не используете

Comment: VK.Widgets.Like("vk_like", {type: "button"});
Так вот же. Или я не так подключаю?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант – предлагать сделать [`wall.post()`](https://vk.com/dev/wall.post) через API, и получать id созданного поста в ответ. [Работающий пример](https://deserter.io/vktest.html).

Подключаете [OpenApi](https://vk.com/dev/openapi), делаете кнопку и примерно такой скрипт:

```
VK.init({ apiId: XXXXXX }); // id вашего приложения ВК, где в настройках прописан ваш домен
document.getElementById('btn-podel').addEventListener('click', hClick); // ждём нажатий на кнопку

function hClick() { // обработчик нажатия
    VK.Api.call('wall.post', {message:"test"}, hPost); 
}

function hPost(r) { // обработчик окончания выполнения API запроса
    if(!r) throw "Bad response from VK";
    if( r.error) { // если отказался постить
        console.log("Not posted. Error:", r.error);
    } else if( r.response) {
        if( r.response.post_id) { // это id свежесозданного поста
            console.log("Posted with id ", r.response.post_id);
        } else {
            console.log("No post id, no idea why", r);
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Not posted, no idea why", r);
    }
}
```

**Недостаток** этого способа в том, что пост делается только на стену пользователя. Нет выбора, как у виджета, куда отправить: себе на стену, в сообщество, личным сообщением.

**Преимущество** – в том, что вы получаете id поста, и, сохранив его у себя, можете через какое-то время проверять, висит ли он ещё, и с тем ли содержанием. Я как-то реализовывал механику, где юзер делал репост, который должен провисеть, как минимум, сутки – только после этого юзер мог получить «награду» – скачать какой-то файл.

Comment: сегодня ваш вариант посмотрю